# Cannot get my Html <input> button to default to my chosen color

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I've written a menu class where the default color is #029BD5. Using the Html methods I've got the menu options changing colour as the mouse passes over them.

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .over {background-color:white;}
    .out {background-color:#029BD5;}
</style>
<html>
    <input type="button" style="height:30px;width:200px;position:absolute; 
        left:150px;top:3px" onmouseover="this.className='over';"
        onmouseout="this.className='out';" onmousedown="this.className='down';" 
        onmouseup="this.className='up';" value="Menu Option 1" 
        onclick="this.value='Option 1 Selected'" />
    <input type="button" style="height:30px;width:200px;position:absolute; 
        left:150px;top:33px" onmouseover="this.className='over';" 
        onmouseout="this.className='out';" onmousedown="this.className='down';" 
        onmouseup="this.className='up';" value="Menu Option 2" 
        onclick="this.value='Option 2 Selected'" />
    <input type="button" style="height:30px;width:200px;position:absolute; 
        left:150px;top:63px" onmouseover="this.className='over';" 
        onmouseout="this.className='out';" onmousedown="this.className='down';" 
        onmouseup="this.className='up';" value="Menu Option 3" 
        onclick="this.value='Option 3 Selected'" />  
</html>
```

The menu options start out as Grey but change to the right colour when the mouse passes over (white and then #029BD5)

I've tried setting the color on each button but then the colour never changes, what am I missing?

Comment: You need to assign the appropriate class to the input element. Currently you are not assigning any color to begin with, only when the mouse moves over the element. But also, you should be using **only** css to do this, not a combination of CSS and JavaScript. The JS part is unnecessary.

Comment: Is this a c# question? Looks like just plain html, css, and javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you over thought it:
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjy4k/1/)**

```
<input type="button" value="Button 1"  />
<input type="button" value="Button 2"  />
<input type="button" value="Button 3"  />
```

And the css

```
input[type="button"]{
    background-color:#029BD5;
}

input[type="button"]:hover{
    background-color:white;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to do this with specific classes for the hover effect.

You can do this with one CSS class and two selectors:

```
input[type=button]{
    background-color:#029BD5;
}

input[type=button]:hover{
    background:white;
}
```

You can clean up your selectors by giving your buttons a class `class='button'`

Then your CSS would be:

```
.button{
    /* define base styles here - borders, width, margins, etc */
    height:30px;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute; 
    left:150px;
    top:3px

    /* define the default background color */
    background-color:#029BD5;
}

.button:hover{ /* Style used on mouseover */
    background-color:white;
    /* Only defining the background-color will override the background-color 
       defined in .button - all other styles from .button will be preserved */
}

.button:active{ /* Style used on mouse click */
    background-color: /* your color */;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use this amount of messy code. Just use the CSS :hover selector instead.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="button" value="Button 1"/>
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="button" value="Button 2"/>
<input type="button" id="btn3" class="button" value="Button 3"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    position:absolute;

    height:30px;
    width:200px;

    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;

    background-color:white;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color:#029BD5;
}

#btn1{
    top:5px;
}
#btn2{
    top:40px;
}
#btn3{
    top:75px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/P5F8d/1/)